# addEventListener in commonjs

Tags: javascript, titanium, commonjs

I need your help on this. Lets say I have 2 files.

file1

```
function test(){
   this.view= Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundColor : 'white'
    });
}
module.exports = test;
```

and in file 2

```
 var view = Ti.UI.createView();
 var a = require('file1');

 a = new test();
 view.add(a.view);
 //no problem
```

And now I want to add eventListeners to the view.

file2

```
 var view = Ti.UI.createView();
 var a = require('file1');
 a=new test();
 view.add(a.view);

 a.view.addEventListener('click',function(){
      a.view.backgroundColor = 'red';
 });

//no problem with this too
```

But is there a way to add eventlisteners to view in file 1? something like this

file1

```
 function test(){
     this.view = Ti.UI.createView({
           backgroundColor : 'white'
     });

     this.view.addEventListener('click',function(){
              this.view.backgroundColor = 'red';
     });
 }
```

Doing this will give me the following error

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event listener is related with the view and with the `test` function. So when you do:

```
this.view.addEventListener('click',function(){
          this.view.backgroundColor = 'red';
 });
```

You are trying to access the `backgroundColor` inside the `view` inside the `this.view`.

Capture the outside scope before you append the event and use it when execute the click:

```
function test(){
     var _this = this;

     this.view = Ti.UI.createView({
         backgroundColor : 'white'
     });

     this.view.addEventListener('click',function(){
         _this.view.backgroundColor = 'red';
     });
 }
```

This should give you the correct reference you are expecting.